# MySQL: Giving all rights over a database to a user but user can't even see database

Tags: java, mysql

### Problem:

I'm using a local MySQL database on Ubuntu 15.10.

I have two users: the root user and a user called `java` with password `password`. The latter is used for a Java JPA test application.

I need `'java'@'localhost'` have all privileges for the `videogames` database (I'm unconcerned with security).

---

### What I did

I use `mysql -u root -p` to get into the console, then do [`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.videogames TO 'java'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016587/3399416).

Then I do `mysql -u java -p` and `show databases`, showing the few databases user `java` has access to but it doesn't show the `videogames` database.

Connecting with the Java/JPA app gives throws an Exception `Access denied for user 'java'@'localhost' to database 'videogames' (Error Code: 1044)`

---

### I have tried:

- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.videogames TO 'java'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'java'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`
- [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13559)
- `sudo service restart mysql`
- [`DROP USER ''`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/3399416)

---

Dumps of the `SHOW GRANTS`s:

- `Grants for java@%`

  - `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'java'@'%'`
  - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mydb'.* TO 'java'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`
  - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mydb'.'videogames' TO 'java'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`
- `Grants for java@localhost`

  - `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'java'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19'`
  - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'javabase'.* TO 'java'@'localhost'`
  - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mydb'.* TO 'java'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`
  - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mydb'.'videogames' TO 'java'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`

---

Dump of [`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7541339/3399416):

`+------------------+--------------------------+
| user             | host                     |
+------------------+--------------------------+
| java             | %                        |
| root             | 127.0.0.1                |
| root             | ::1                      |
| root             | (name of my pc)          |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost                |
| java             | localhost                |
| root             | localhost                |
+------------------+--------------------------+`

---

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

video games is a database and not a table.

everything before the dot is database, after it is the table.

so this would be right:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON videogames.* TO 'java'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```